How do i handle branches in CI/CD AZURE Dev Ops
I am trying to create a development area in my project, I have created a development branch in my repo and I have created pipelines to build that branch to the development function.
I maybe missing something but when I merge branches to the master, its going to merge the pipelines (yaml files) (which are the same with the exception of the trigger), do i just not merge the pipeline or is there a better way to to manage this?
To add further context:
I am trying to create a environments;
one for production and one for development, in the production environment it has a function which has a staging slot, so when the master branch is updated it, uses the master branches pipeline script which restores builds and deploys an artifact to the drop folder (which is the yaml file) which is then used in the release pipeline to deploy to the staging slot (the release pipeline is done in the portal).
the development environment also has a function but not slot at the moment, but also has a pipeline scipt in the development branch of the same repo  which restores builds and deploys an artifact to the drop folder (which is the yaml file) which is then used in the release pipeline to deploy to the development function.
They each have there own apim to allow mapping to seperat sub domains domain name.
As far as I am aware the pipelines have to be seperate as I only want the development function to update when the development branch is pushed to and i only want to production staging slot to be pushed to if the master branch is pushed to, meaning the trigger lines have to be different as the trigger is different.
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/nuget.config'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release'


- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'


As opposed to the classical build and release pipelines (UI-based), YAML pipelines can be seen as "pipelines-as-code", and are part of your repositories - it makes sense to merge them to master or any other branch.
This means you can manage changes or fixes in the pipelines in the same way you manage changes or fixes in any other file in the repository:

The pipeline is versioned with your code. It follows the same branching structure. You get validation of your changes through code reviews in pull requests and branch build policies.
Every branch you use can modify the pipeline by modifying the corresponding .yml file (or shared YAML templates used by the pipeline)
A change to the build process might cause a break or result in an unexpected outcome. Because the change is in version control with the rest of your codebase, you can more easily identify the issue

See Use Azure Pipelines for more details.
EDIT
Regarding your specific case, you can use one and only one YAML pipeline to build the app and deploy to the right environment, depending on the branch.
Example on how to configure the stages using conditions:
trigger:
  - master
  - development

variables:
  - name: isProduction
    value: $[ contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'master') ]

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
          - script: echo "Building the app"

  ###################################################### Dev stages

  - stage: DeployDev
    displayName: 'Deploy to Dev (production slot)'
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isProduction'], 'false'))
    jobs:
      - job: DeployDev
        displayName: 'Deploy to Dev'
        variables:
          # Declaring variables here for demonstration purposes only
          - name: functionAppName
            value: 'my-function-app-dev'
          - name: slotName
            value: 'production'
          # Variables templates should be used instead
          # - template: /pipelines/variables/dev-variables.yaml
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "Deploying $(functionAppName) to slot $(slotName)"
            displayName: 'Deploy to dev'
  
    ###################################################### Prod stages

  - stage: DeployProd
    displayName: 'Deploy to Prod (staging slot)'
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isProduction'], 'true'))
    jobs:
      - job: DeployProd
        displayName: 'Deploy to Prod (staging slot)'
        variables:
          # Declaring variables here for demonstration purposes only
          - name: functionAppName
            value: 'my-function-app-prod'
          - name: slotName
            value: 'staging'
          # Variables templates should be used instead
          # - template: /pipelines/variables/prod-variables.yaml
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "Deploying $(functionAppName) to slot $(slotName)"
            displayName: 'Deploy to prod'
  
  - stage: SwapProdSlots
    displayName: 'Swap prod slots'
    dependsOn: DeployProd
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isProduction'], 'true'))
    jobs:
      - job: SwapProdSlots
        displayName: 'Swap prod slots'
        variables:
          # Declaring variables here for demonstration purposes only
          - name: functionAppName
            value: 'my-function-app-prod'
          - name: sourceSlotName
            value: 'staging'
          # Variables templates should be used instead
          # - template: /pipelines/variables/prod-variables.yaml
        steps:
          - script: echo "Swapping $(sourceSlotName) with production slot in $(functionAppName)"
            displayName: 'Swap slots'

Please note that I'm using conditions to determine which stage to run, based on the source branch:
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isProduction'], 'true'))

Running the build when changes are commited to the development branch:

Running the build when changes are commited to the production branch:

Remember to set environments to set approvals to the jobs, if required.

thanks but my concept of branches as they move nearer to the master they are supported to be more and more similar, but yaml pipeline files are always going to be different, and there is a substantial risk if the trigger on the pipeline gets mixed up and not noticed. I was hoping i could do something to mitigate that risk.

yaml pipeline files are always going to be different - why ALWAYS? it's ok to have occasional changes as mentioned in my answer, but I can't think of a scenario where these files always change. Please elaborate, and add more details to your question.

And add some of the pipeline code, if it helps to understand your question.

Just to be clear, you can use one and only one pipeline to deploy to several environments, without changing it for each branch.

My pipeline is farely simple, it just restores builds and deployes a .NET project for an azure function app to the artifacts, that is then used in the release pipeline to deploy the function. I have two functions, one for production with has staging slot and one for development, but there is two branches, the master for production and the development for development, when an update gets pushed to development it updates the developement repos pipeline which has a development repo trigger, and goes to the development release pipeline, the same for the production.

the about post keeps says master and development repos but i ment branches of the same repo, i have added more detail to the op.

i also guess i could just have two and give them different names but thats doesn't feel very clean

Thanks for the info, I have it working in one file now, however i now have the problem where the code will be in two branches, do i just consider the master branch version a backup and use the development branch one as the one registered in the devops pipeline? (the biggest thing i don't like is having the production pipeline code in the dev branch

@EnenDaveyBoy pipeline code needs to be merged into all branches from where you'll run your code. Not sure if I understand your concern? If you want to deploy dev, you need the pipeline in dev branch. If you want to deploy prod, you need to the pipeline in prod branch. But don't worry because if you design it well as the pipeline code won't change that often.

Thanks for all the help, ill post the pipeline later in the op

Sorry I have just re red your comment, and that seems to suggest that, i would register a pipeline in both branchs but if I did that due to the trigger being both branchs it will run twice and deloy twice which is a pointless and I am sure dev ops wouldn't appriciated it.

@EnenDaveyBoy you register/create the pipeline in the Azure DevOps portal only once. But if you want to run it from multiple branches, you need to have the source file (e.g. azure-pipeline.yaml) in all the branches.

You can have two separate pipelines with two yaml files, one for each environment. You can name them differently to avoid confusion, such as azure-pipelines-development.yml and azure-pipelines-production.yml.
In each pipeline file, you can specify the branch trigger.
# azure-pipelines-development.yml
trigger:
- development

# azure-pipelines-production.yml
trigger:
- master

In this way, you can ensure that each environment is updated correctly based on the changes in its respective branch and branch merge will not affect pipelines.

thanks for the help, i sort of came to that conclusion if i hadn't had the response above, but this also has a little messs, with masses of duplicate code and although the same issue as above having the master pipeline code in the development branch

Hi @EnenDaveyBoy, if you will not merge the master branch to the development branch, the master pipeline code will not be in the development branch.  In addition, even if two branches have these two yaml files through some merge, you can ignore the redundant yaml file and focus on the right file of the branch. Of course, which method to use depends on your preference. Happy coding!
